# decrement a python pandas column relativly to an other one

Tags: python, pandas

I have this structure with column B holding the number of same occurrence of the value of column A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('aaabbcccc'), B=list('333224444')))
df
#    A  B
# 0  a  3
# 1  a  3
# 2  a  3
# 3  b  2
# 4  b  2
# 5  c  4
# 6  c  4
# 7  c  4
# 8  c  4
```

I look for an elegant way to add the C column, that decrement for each line the value of B.

```
res
#    A  B  C
# 0  a  3  2
# 1  a  3  1
# 2  a  3  0
# 3  b  2  1
# 4  b  2  0
# 5  c  4  3
# 6  c  4  2
# 7  c  4  1
# 8  c  4  0
```

Comment: I'm not clear by what amount you are trying to decrement the value in B. Each of the lines in your example are decremented by varying amounts, and I can't determine how this amount relates to B. What exactly is the relation between B and C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cumcount(ascending=False)`, as suggested by @ALollz:

```
df.groupby('B').cumcount(ascending=False)

0    2
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    3
6    2
7    1
8    0
dtype: int64
```